# How to write this code in python any help would be appreciated

Tags: python

def read_file(fp)  list of tuples

i. The parameter is a file pointer. Read the whole file to extract data from columns 1 and 10; return a list of tuples. Because column 1 has commas within the field and the file is a comma-separated-value file (csv) use the csv module (see program notes below).

There is one header line that needs to be skipped.

Column 1 has the county and state, separated by a comma.

The state is the twoletter abbreviation. Call the get_county_state to separate the county and state.

Column 10 has the median income for the county. The income is an
integer, but values over a thousand have commas that need to be handled. If there is no value for income, ignore that county.

All other columns can be ignored. Return a list of tuples where each tuple is (state, county, median_income)

Sort the list in decreasing order of median_income. Hint: use itemgetter from the operator module (see program notes below).

ii. Parameters: file pointer

iii. Returns: sorted list of tuples

iv. Display: nothing

This is the code that I have the for problem at the moment. I am very lost and would appreciate any help!

```
def read_file(fp):
    
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    
    next(reader, None)
    for row in reader:
        country_state = row[1]
        country_state = get_county_state(country_state)
        state_str = country_state[-1]
        country_str = country_state[0]
        state = state_str
        country = country_str
        median_income = row[10]
        median_income = int(median_income)
        read_file = (state, country, median_income)
        return read_file
```

Comment: "file pointer" is really not a great description in Python. You generally aren't working with actual file pointers. Almost certainly, it means a file object.

Comment: This problem isn't very fit for Stack Overflow. Try to refrain from asking questions when there are resources online to help you answer this very question. You may want to look up how to do this before coming here.

Comment: "I am very lost" is hard to interpret. It looks like you wrote some code. It looks like the instructions are telling you to use itemgetter, but you didn't get that far? Which piece do you want help with?

Comment: Consider using pandas for these kind of data manipulations

Comment: @PooyaKamranjam why? This is all trivially implemented with the standard library and built-in functions.

Comment: @PooyaKamranjam--also this looks like a homework exercise so other libraries (such as Pandas) may be prohibited. Specific instructions (assume from the instructor) were to use the CSV module and itemgetter from the operator module.

Comment: pandas is very efficient for vectorized operations on arrays and it's specifically designed for these kind of problems, plus the code is much more readable and shorter @juanpa.arrivillaga You need to take a look at pandas docs!

Comment: @PooyaKamranjam--I'm very familiar with Pandas and think it's great.  However, coders need to learn some basic programming and practice solving problems in order to sharpen their skills.  I only mention this because of other coders I run across on this site who lament about never learning the basics.

Comment: @PooyaKamranjam--P.S.--I didn't downvote your answer (I never downvote answers).

Answer (score -2):

You need to first install pandas, then do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

def read_file(fp):
    df = pd.read_csv(fp)
    df[['state','country']] = pd.DataFrame(df.country_state.tolist(), index= df.index)
    df = df[['state', 'country', 'median_income']]
    return df.values.tolist()
```